# Flip text animation After Effects

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects

I know how to flip text on AE, but I'd like to *animate* the flip and I couldn't find a tutorial for that.

I have a 9 and I want to copy it and flip it like opening a book like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question... I have to go to the text layer I want to animate, click on animate, select enable per-character 3D and then change Y Rotation to -180 degrees.

This tutorial helped http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/creating-3d-flip-down-text-in-after-effects/